# magento 2 remove iteam from wishlist

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist

In **wishlist.php** I am trying to add remove from wishlist.

I have created a block and pasted the code of remove from wishlist..
It seems some issue.

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getWishlistItemId() on null in PG2\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Helper\Data.php on line 283
```

My code

```
 // Get LoggedIn user wishlist.
$wishlistProductsIds = $block->getCurrentWishListProductIDs();

 // Get product id.
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
 $productID = $product->getId();
?>

<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>

    <?php if (in_array($productID, $wishlistProductsIds)): ?>

        <style type="text/css"> .product-social-links .action.towishlist::before { color:#F4804F; } </style>

        <?php 
        $blockObjx = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock');


        // echo $productID . gettype($productID);

        // echo $blockObjx->getRemoveParams((object)$productID);

        // // echo $blockObjx->getItemRemoveParams($blockObjx->getItem());

        // exit;
        ?>


    <a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-role="remove" data-post-remove='<?php echo $blockObjx->getItemRemoveParams($blockObjx->getItem()); ?>' title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Remove Item') ?>" class="btn-remove action delete">
        <span><?php echo __('Remove from Wish List');?></span>
    </a>


    <?php else: ?>   

        <!-- Display add to wish list default functionalitiy. -->
        <a href="#"
               class="action towishlist"
               data-post='<?php echo $block->getWishlistParams(); ?>'
               data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?php echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span></a>


    <?php endif; ?>


<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
 {
    "body": {
        "addToWishlist": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
    }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Addto\Wishlist
 */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = $block->getProduct();

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper */
$wishlistHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');
$wishlistItem = $wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()->getItemByColumnValue('product_id', $product->getId());

?>
<?php if($block->isWishListAllowed()): ?>
    <?php if($wishlistItem): ?>
        <a href="#" data-post='<?= $wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem) ?>'>
            <?= __('Remove from Wish List') ?>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="#" data-post='<?= $block->getWishlistParams() ?>'>
            <?= __('Add to Wish List') ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this helps.